# Rotating a 2D object drawn with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rotation

I made a fancy shape with OpenGL and I draw that shape this function:

```
drawShape(const Point & center, char radius, int points, int rotation)
```

Inside the function I have code that tells OpenGL where the vertexes are:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glVertex2f(center.getX() + 0.0, center.getY() + 1.0);
  // more vertices
glEnd();
```

Now when I add `glRotatef(rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`, I would like just this shape that I have drawn to rotate on the screen.  However, if I add it above `glBegin()` it rotates everything in the window. If I include all the code between `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` rotates the object, but around the center of the window. How can I rotate just the object that I have drawn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing OpenGL's job by having `center.getX` and such added to the values.

What you want is this:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(center.getX(), center.getY(), 0.0f);
glRotatef(rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glVertex2f(0.0, 1.0);
  // more vertices
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

You can probably apply the radius by using a `glScale` matrix and assuming a radius of 1.0 in your `glVertex` calls.

Comment: In addition I suggest you learn to use vertex arrays and vertex buffer objects, and do away with immediate mode (i.e. no longer use glBegin…glEnd).